# multiprocessing.Queue hanging when Process dies

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a subprocess via `multiprocessing.Process` and a queue via `multiprocessing.Queue`.

The main process is using `multiprocessing.Queue.get()` to get some new data. I don't want to have a timeout there and I want it to be blocking.

However, when the child process dies for whatever reason (manually killed by user via `kill`, or segfault, etc.), `Queue.get()` just will hang forever.

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `multiprocessing.Queue` is not what I want.

I'm using now

```
parent_conn, child_conn = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=True)
```

to get two `multiprocessing.Connection` objects. Then I `os.fork()` or use `multiprocessing.Process`. In the child, I do:

```
parent_conn.close()
# read/write on child_conn
```

In the parent (after the fork), I do:

```
child_conn.close()
# read/write on parent_conn
```

That way, when I call `recv()` on the connection, it will raise an exception (`EOFError`) when the child/parent dies in the meanwhile.

Note that this works only for a single child. I guess `Queue` is meant when you want multiple childs. In that case, you would probably anyway have some manager which watches whether all childs are alive and restarts them accordingly.

Comment: Good catch. I tried `Pipe` when responding here, but I did not get an EOF error when the client died. I think I forgot to close the connection.

Answer (score 2):

The `Queue` has no way of knowing when it does not have any possible writers anymore. You could pass the object to any number of subprocesses, and it does not know if you passed it to any given subprocess. So it will have to wait, even if a subprocess dies. A queue is *not* a file descriptor that is automatically closed when the child dies.

What you are looking for is some kind of supervisor in the parent process that notices when children die unexpectedly and handle that situation in whatever way you think appropriate. You can do this by catching a `SIGCHLD` process, checking `Process.is_alive` or using `Process.join` in a thread. A simple implementation would use the `timeout` parameter in the `Queue.get` call and do a `Process.is_alive` check when that returns.

If you have a bit more control over the death of the child process, it should send an "EOF"-type object (`None`, or some kind of marker that it is done) to the queue so your parent process can handle it correctly.

Comment: Ofc I could send EOF, but that would never cover all cases, such as a `kill -9` by the user, a segfault or similar. timeout is also no real solution because I don't want it to hang at all - there is no reason to hang for nothing. I could use SIGCHLD but that seems a bit like overkill. The background thread seems also like some waste of resources to do just that which should also be possible in simpler ways.